# Symfony session variable gets lost in ipad

Tags: ipad, symfony-1.4, php

I am working on a symfony application. It works fine in all browsers and even Mac safari.
The issues exists only in ipad. Few of my session variables gets lost in other pages. 
  for example:

I set the session as :

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('domainname', $this->domain);
```

This value could be retrieved in other pages in every browsers by :

```
 $this->domain = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('domainname');
```

But in ipad device (safari), my variables are not retrieving.

Comment: Did you `var_dump($this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->getAll())` your session?

Comment: Yes. In ipad few of the session variables show NULL. But i retrieve all the variables in other browser.

Comment: What if you logout/login ? Does the problem appear on iPad Safari only, or also on iPad Chrome?

Comment: Login/logout does not affect the feature. The issue exists in ipad safari.

Comment: The issue exists in ipad chrome also. Is it due to any ipad settings?

Comment: I've no idea .. maybe.

Comment: Any one has any idea ?

Comment: Seems like the issue exists in android also. So is this any issue with only devices?

Comment: I too have this issue on using symfony projects in mobile devices. I had updated symfony forum. But they haven't replied.

Comment: Would like to know about this as well

Answer (score 0):

Check the session ID storage mechanism. Is the session ID stored in cookies or on files in the server, db or other methods. If its in cookies and your Ipad browsers dont allow cookies thats most likely the reason.
http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php